# How to build a tick for loop without using the loop variable

Tags: go, intervals

I have a for loop that continually runs over an interval, however I am only using it as a function that I want running every 10 Minutes. How can I declare this for-loop without having to use 'x' somewhere inside of the loop

```
interval := time.Tick(10 * time.Minute)

for x := range interval {
  ...code that does not use x
}
```

I have tried restructuring the for loop but nothing results in it running without specifically using 'x', I know I could just simply do something with 'x' inside of the loop, but I would rather learn how to properly implement this for loop then make a hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either

```
for {
        <-time.After(someTime)
        // ...
}
```

or

```
interval := time.Tick(someTime)

for ; ; <-interval { // First interval == 0
        // ...
}
```

or

```
interval := time.Tick(someTime)

for {
        <-interval
        // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think the second form will compile (for <- interval), the channel returns a time.Time value, not a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `_` to denote variables that you will ignore:

```
interval := time.Tick(10 * time.Minute)

for _ = range interval {
  ...
}
```

The [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) says:

> The blank identifier, represented by the underscore character _, may
>   be used in a declaration like any other identifier but the declaration
>   does not introduce a new binding.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I declare this for-loop without having to use 'x' somewhere inside of the loop

Starting go1.4 (Q4 2014), you will be able to do:

```
for range interval {
  ...
}
```

See [go tip 1.4 doc](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.4#forrange):

> as of Go 1.4 the **variable-free form is now legal**.
>   The pattern arises rarely but the code can be cleaner when it does.
>
> Updating: The change is strictly backwards compatible to existing Go programs, but tools that analyze Go parse trees may need to be modified to accept this new form as the `Key` field of `RangeStmt` may now be `nil`.